# How to push data from local machine (computer) to Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure

I created a simple text file in NotePad, it is a .txt file. I want to push this data to an azure table, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this in c#. Does anyone know how I can push some sample data from my computer to an azure table? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. This should get you started, next time do some research and ask a question if you experience problems with code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet

Comment: Not a standard question for SO, but i will give you some directions. Learn how to read/write files with C#(related with System IO). Then learn how to work with databases. Then learn about ADO.Net. Then learn about Entity Framework. Learn about SQL, Sql Server/MySql, Sql Queries. Then choose either ADO.Net or Entity framework. Then read the text file, insert the data into Azure database. Then learn about SQL Injection. Try to improve your SQL queries. And so on. That's all the help i can do here for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic steps for doing this:

1. [Read the text file into memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file).

We can do that with a single line of code:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");
```

2. [Authenticate to Azure Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-tables).

You will need to get the relevant nuget packages for Azure Storage. You could write the code without the SDK, but I don't recommend it.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
    new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
        "<name>", "<account-key>"), true);

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Get a reference to a table named "textTable"
CloudTable textTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("textTable");
```

3. [Write to Azure Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-tables).

We need to make a class that defines the data structure we are uploading into storage. Every entity must have a row key and a partition key.

```
public class TextEntity : TableEntity
{
    public TextEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public TextEntity() { }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

We can then use that class to create the object that we will then upload to storage.

```
var tableEntry = new TextEntry("partitionKey", "rowKey");
tableEntry.Text = text;

TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(tableEntry);

// Execute the insert operation.
await textTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
```